# massive DB storing common calculated values vs/ calculating it on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i am building a PHP+MySQL for my employer to see the statistics per sales-guy over the past months and years.
the idea is to show the sales revenue per employee. there is a lot of employee (current and past employee).
the statistics table i am thinking of is like this:

```
table_sales_revenue
id
id_sales_guy
Year
year_nbr
jan_nbr
feb_nbr
mar_nbr
etc..
dec_nbr
```

so for Sales Guy John

```
id=1
id_sales_guy=1231852
year=2011
year_nbr=12k
avg_day=32.8  (that's year_nbr/365, bcse they work 7/7)
jan_nbr=1k
feb_nbr=1k
etc..
dec_nbr=1k
```

I am storing the year nbr value which is the sum of the month_nbr, because the user of this app, will compare a lot based on the year_nbr, and then for more details he will go thru the month details. so i am storing it to avoid calculating it every time. is that good?

is it useful to add the first 'id' field(auto-increment, PK) to boost perf?
thanks

Comment: Having a separate field for every month seems a little clumsy. Have you considered a separate table for sales numbers, linked by the employee ID, with one record per person per month? It might not make your queries appreciably faster but it would certainly make them easier to read and maintain (`select nbr from sales where id_sales_guy=1231852 and year=2011` instead of `select jan_nbr, feb_nbr, mar_nbr...`).

Comment: i forgot to mention, that the jan_nbr , feb_nbr, are not necessarly the same amount. so your above suggestion can't be applied. thanks anyway

Comment: They don't have to be the same number. The sales table has one row for each person for each month, recording their sales number for that month. Whey you run the query I mentioned you get 12 rows for the year 2011, each with a month and a sales number.

Answer (score 1):

This question really is subjective and depends on the actual quantities of calculations being done. Generally speaking,if you are going to be doing large amounts of calculations, and your database truly is `massive` then yes - it is good to store some values. You'll be happier with the return time of your queries. Otherwise, performance gains and losses can be minimal.